# Corse headers adding Error while using Django in IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, django-cors-headers

I have a django application which is hosted in IIS (with custom URL) and its front end is hosted in Angular. The front end is showing corse related error so i tried to resolve that by adding 'corseheaders' in settings.py of my backend code. After that when i tried to access the API (by clicking the hosted URL in IIS) the following error is showing in the browser.

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TESTAPP\API\venv\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
```

Following is the changes i have done in the settings.py of my backend(django). Actually i have added the last line with "corsheaders". if its removed the error is gone.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'survey_app.apps.SurveyAppConfig',
'corsheaders',
]
```

Can you guys please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The frontend showing corse related errors is due to your frontend not being on the same domain as your Django API/backend, so all Django responses need to contain CORS related headers. This [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is about Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

On how to use django-cors-headers to solve cross-domain problems, you can refer to the following steps:

1.Install the package using pip:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

2.Add "corseheaders" to settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ……
        'corsheaders',
        ……
    )
```

3.Add middleware:

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        ...
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        ...
    ]
```

4.Add the following configuration in settings.py:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    '*'
)
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'VIEW',
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'XMLHttpRequest',
    'X_FILENAME',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
    'Pragma',
)
```

For more detailed configuration, please refer to the official [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).